# Output conditional field in Umbraco:item

Tags: umbraco

Outputting a field in Umbraco is pretty straight forward:

```
<umbraco:Item runat="server" field="introduction">
```

Lets say I'm currently rendering an article with the property 'introduction'. In case the article introduction field is empty I want instead to output a more global field on the home site node, let's call it 'global_introduction'.

Does anybody know how to do this?

I know about the optional attribute `xslt`, but don't know if it will suffice... or exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

you could set recursive="true", and keep the variable names the same.  Then, when umbraco doesn't find the value, it will default to the parent node value.

```
<umbraco:Item runat="server" field="introduction" recursive="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<umbraco:item field="bodyText" useIfEmpty="altText" runat="server"/>
```